# How to find intersection point coordinate from two MKCircle in map-kit?

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit, ipa, mkcircle

I have two cordinates and radius values, using that i am drawing two circle on mapview. Now i have to find the two intersection coordinates, where two circle cross each other. same image shown below:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/256100/533020

Comment: @the4kman i am not asking for math equation, I want the map coordinates (lat,lon).